# What is this situation called and how do I avoid it?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, filament, petg, colorfabb-xt

I am trying to print ColorFabb XT-Filament PETG on my Kobra Max, and I get the following results:

[image: Mess]

These are my Cura settings:

[image: Cura settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### WAY too low print temperature/wrong material Profile

That's a PLA profile with 195 °C on the printhead. PETG is recommended between 230 °C and 250 °C. Load a PETG-Profile. in Cura, the material (which dictates print temperature) is a separate thing and can be swapped independent of many other settings, especially how detailed you print. However, very careful piece of advice:

**Save your profile before swapping materials!**

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a PETG profile. I will change the settings according to your recommendation. Edit: Oh, I find an instruction how to activate a profile for PETG in Cura: https://all3dp.com/2/cura-petg-settings-profile/

Comment: yes, you can just swap the material in CURA, which swaps print temp and some other things.

Comment: The advised temperature of ColorFabb XT is 240-260 °C and a bed temperature of 60-70 °C.

Comment: Real PETG needs at least 245 or so to print decently at all, and preferably 260 or so if your printer can handle it safely (needs all-metal hotend). Fake "PETG" can be all sorts of random plastics mixed together and might print anywhere from 210 to 250.